# How are databases managed in social networking cites?

Tags: database, bigdata

I am interested in understanding how the social networking sites like Facebook, Twitter, Google+ maintain their databases. In which format the data is stored in their database. I am completely new in this field and any description would be beneficial.

Comment: These kind of questions are not for SO, you should locate the appropriate SE site for this. Or you could just google it, I typed in "facebook database" and many results returned about how and what facebook use for their DB. Do some research, don't expect others to do it for you

Comment: A good start would be to look at and read up on how to manage big databases, as it's a whole different ballpark to small time shopping databases. Saying that, I think looking at something like ebay which is (or at least was) a massive Magento store DB,. download Magento and learn it as it's a decent introduction to EAV databasing

Comment: See now these are the sort of questions you as on quora.[for example like this one](http://www.quora.com/What-databases-are-used-by-Twitter-Facebook-TripAdvisor-FourSquare-Open-Street-Map-Google-Maps-and-Quora).You would have reached here via one google search.Please utilise Google search(and then SO search) to its fullest before posting a question

Answer (score 4):

For Social networking sites. you can use [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) Graph DataBase. realiable for any social networking sites. i prefer for you bcz i used that.